# Recursive function accounting for Negative y values in scheme through a multiply procedure

Tags: scheme, racket

So far, I am only accounting for positive number(s) and negative x values. I am unsure on how to account for negative  y values. Here is what I have,

```
(define (Multiply x y)
(if (= y 0)
0
(+x (Multiply x ( - y 1))
(if (< y 0) //here is where i try to account for negative numbers.
(+ x( - 0 (Multiply x(+ y 1))))))
)
(Multiply 8 3) //outputs 24
(Multiply -9 3) //outputs -27
```

I need to find a way to account for negative y values. A bit confused of how to do so.
Very new to scheme, anything will help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was going to suggest dealing with only positive numbers in the recursion and using a wrapper to turn the negative inputs positive and then negating the result if only one of the original inputs was negative.

Comment: The wrapper would look like `(define (multiply a b) (let ((p (multiply-unsigned (abs a) (abs b)))) (if (xor (a < 0) (b < 0)) (- p) p)))`

Comment: in your example, (multiply-unsigned):  undefined;

Comment: You would define that function. I was only attempting to show how to separate out the sign from the multiplication.

Comment: so are you saying i should make use of a hyper function? I have to implement my multiply procedure by a sequence of additions.

Comment: @Camkin see [Recursive Multiplication in Scheme (trouble with negatives)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49910863/4739247).

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (both-same-sign a b)
  (if (and (> a 0) (> b 0)) #t
  (if (and (< a 0) (< b 0)) #t
  #f)))

(define (make-positive n)
  (if (< n 0) (- n)
  n))

(define (multiply x y)
  (define a (make-positive x))
  (define b (make-positive y))
  (define (multiplier a b)
    (if (or (= a 0) (= b 0)) 0
    (+ a (multiplier a (- b 1)))))
  (define result (multiplier a b))
  (if (both-same-sign x y) result
   (- result)))
```